# SwiftUI decode JSON data and show in a list - Decode error

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm building a simple weather application using SwiftUI and open weather map APIs. To display the forecast weather, I have used the below API call.

```
    func getForecastWeather() async throws -> ForecastResponseBody {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&appid=api-key") else {fatalError("Missing URL")}

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)

        guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { fatalError("Error fetching weather data")}

        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastResponseBody.self, from: data)

        print(decodedData)

        return decodedData
    }
```

The JSON model is like this

```
import Foundation

struct ResponseBodyByForecast: Decodable {
    var cod: String
    var message: Double
    var list: [forecastList]
    
    
    struct forecastList: Decodable {
        var main: ForecastMainResponse
        var weather: ForecastWeatherResponse
        var clouds: ForecastCloudResponse
        var dt_txt: String
    }
    
    struct ForecastMainResponse:Decodable{
        var temp_min: Double
        var temp_max: Double
        var humidity: Double
        var pressure: Double
    }
    
    struct ForecastWeatherResponse:Decodable{
        var id: Double
        var main: String
        var description: String
        
    }
    
    struct ForecastCloudResponse:Decodable{
        var all: Double
    }
    
}
```

And the actual JSON response is

```
      

{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1647345600,
      "main": {
        "temp": 286.88,
        "feels_like": 285.93,
        "temp_min": 286.74,
        "temp_max": 286.88,
        "pressure": 1021,
        "sea_level": 1021,
        "grnd_level": 1018,
        "humidity": 62,
        "temp_kf": 0.14
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 85
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 3.25,
        "deg": 134,
        "gust": 4.45
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-03-15 12:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1647356400,
      "main": {
        "temp": 286.71,
        "feels_like": 285.77,
        "temp_min": 286.38,
        "temp_max": 286.71,
        "pressure": 1021,
        "sea_level": 1021,
        "grnd_level": 1017,
        "humidity": 63,
        "temp_kf": 0.33
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 90
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 3.34,
        "deg": 172,
        "gust": 4.03
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-03-15 15:00:00"
    },

    ...

 ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 51.5073,
      "lon": -0.1277
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 1000000,
    "timezone": 0,
    "sunrise": 1647324903,
    "sunset": 1647367441
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error while accessing the decoded data. I can see the API response, and it is printing via the API call function. But unable to access data. This is how I tried to access the data,

```
import SwiftUI

struct ForecastView: View {
    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    @State var weather: ForecastResponseBody?
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
        
            .onAppear {
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        weather = try await weatherManager.getForecastWeather()
                        print("Weather" , weather)
                        
                    } catch {
                        print("Error occured while fetching your weather results: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
}

struct ForecastView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForecastView()
    }
}
```

I'm getting Swift.DecodingError.

The full error code:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "list", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "weather", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: You are decoding `ForecastResponseBody`, you're not decoding any of the types you posted in your code. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I added only a print statement to check whether the data is available or not. I added a list to display the data from the response, but it didn't work. That's why I removed it before asking this question. Thank you so much for your reply, and I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON data has array of Weather but you have single object in your model. See

```
 "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
```

the square brackets indicate that this is an array. But in your model you are mapping this on a Dictionary.
The solution is either remove these brackets from your JSON file or make the weather in your model like this

```
var weather: [ForecastWeatherResponse]
```

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you so much for pointing out this. It helped me to resolve my problem.

Comment: @JayamalSanukaHettiarachchi Nice! Please accept the answer so others can also take benefit from it.